# Add a short description to Recent Post Widget?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there away I can add a short description for each Recent Post under each title in the Recent Post Widget?

```
For Example:

Recent Post 1 
Short Description 1 
READ MORE

Recent Post 2 
Short Description 2 
READ MORE

etc etc
```

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a short description for the posts using the excerpt function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: Hi, Figured out where to put it :) is there away i can set a character limit or should I use CSS to hide overflow? Cheers Joe